# hide previous div when next div's display is none or hidden in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to hide a previous div when my next div's display is none or if its hidden.

```
<div id="first"> Hello </div>
<div id="second">
  <div id="secondchild1" style="display:none"> How are you.? </div>
  <div id="secondchild2" style="display:none"> Nice to meet you </div>
</div>
```

Now i need to hide first when all the child divs in second are hidden or thier display is none.

And even when one of the child divs are displayed, the first should also be displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, but we don't going to do it for you take a look to this post :http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over all divs inside the #second div to check whether the current child div is visible or not. If it's visible exit the function and set boolean to true. Lastly, show or hide the #first div based on the boolean value.

```
var showFirst = false;
$('#second div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        showFirst = true;
        return false;
    }
});
showFirst ? $('#first').show() : $('#first').hide();​
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/Az3aW/

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#second").children().css("display") != "none")
{
    $("#first").css("display", "none");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#second').children().each(function(){
    if($(this).css('display') == 'none') $('#first').hide();
});
```

When you get one display none hide

Comment: this isn't working as it hides the `#first` div element if the last child has `display: none`

Comment: @micadelli ops: i've not considerate the last part of question ("when one of the child divs are displayed, the first should also be displayed"), your solution works ;-)